# How to add new woocommerce attribute type?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce has two attribute type (text , select) !

How can I add new attribute type **checkbox**

I prefer to don't use plugin : )

Comment: Create a new custom field in post_type product.
Search about add custom field in wordpress

Comment: @KayoBruno i can make custom field - but you can move attributes in woo..   and add or rermove theme

Answer (score 4):

Tip: If You want to add it to functions.php or what I prefer to split my code using single Responsibility pattern then create class and instantiate it.

```
add_filter("product_attributes_type_selector" , function( $array ){
    $array["checkbox"] = __( 'Checkbox', 'woocommerce' );
    return $array ;
});
```